# Add Business Days

Tags: apex, date, holidays

I am trying to add business days to a date using an invocable method. I cannot use the formula method as I need to take into account holidays as well as weekends.

```
 public static Date addBussinessDays(Date startDate, Integer iDays)
    {
        Date endDate = startDate.addDays(iDays);
        Integer iOffDays = daysOff(startDate, endDate);
        return endDate.addDays(iOffDays);
    }

    public static Integer daysOff(DateTime sdate, DateTime edate)
    {
        Integer iCount = 0;
        while (sdate < edate) {
            Date d = date.newInstance(sdate.year(), sdate.month(),sdate.day());
            if ((sdate.format('E') == 'Sat' | sdate.format('E') == 'Sun') | checkifItisWorkingDay(d)) {
                iCount = iCount + 1;
            }
            sdate = sdate.addDays(1);
        }
        return iCount;
    }

    public static boolean checkifItisWorkingDay(Date currentDate){
        List<Holiday> holidays=[Select h.StartTimeInMinutes, h.Name, h.ActivityDate From Holiday h];

        Date weekStart  = currentDate.toStartofWeek();
        for(Holiday hDay:holidays){
            if(currentDate.daysBetween(hDay.ActivityDate) == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) ==0 || weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) == 6){
            return false;
        } else 
            return true;

    }
```

My codes just doesn't seam to work, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: check the value of iDays and iOffDays. May be one of them is negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

** updated the answer after comments **

The mechanism of adding 'extra days' to the starting day does not guarantee that you end up on a non-working day. Instead of that you will need to loop through all days one by one, check if they're working days, and if not, continue the loop without adding anything.

Also you are currently doing query (for holidays) in a loop. This can  be optimized to prevent Governor Limit errors when calculating with more than 100 days.

The code could look like this:

```
public static Date addBussinessDays(Date startDate, Integer iDays)
{
    Integer businessDaysAdded = 0;
    Date currentDate = startDate;
    while (businessDaysAdded < iDays) {
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
        Datetime d = datetime.newInstance(currentDate.year(), currentDate.month(),currentDate.day());

        if (d.format('E') != 'Sat' && d.format('E') != 'Sun' && checkifItisWorkingDay(currentDate)) {
            // it's a business day, so add 1 to the counter that works towards the amount of days to add
            businessDaysAdded = businessDaysAdded + 1;
        } 
    }       
    return currentDate;
}

public static List<Holiday> holidays {
    get {
        if(holidays == null)
            holidays=[Select h.StartTimeInMinutes, h.Name, h.ActivityDate From Holiday h];
        return holidays;
    }
    private set;
}

public static boolean checkifItisWorkingDay(Date currentDate){
    Date weekStart  = currentDate.toStartofWeek();
    for(Holiday hDay:holidays){
        if(currentDate.daysBetween(hDay.ActivityDate) == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) ==0 || weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) == 6){
        return false;
    } else 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @guy I have changed my method name, and added the negative check. The code still returns an end date of Saturday if you set the Start Date as a Friday. It should return and end date of the Monday, as that is the next working day

Comment: Yes, the mechanism of adding 'extra days' to the starting day does not guarantee that you end up on a non-working day. Instead of that you will need to loop through all days one by one, check if they're working days, and if not, continue the loop without adding anything. I will update my answer with an example.